# Class cast exception in CronJob

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I had created a custom cron job model in items.xml like ::

```
<itemtype code="MyCustomCronJob" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="CronJob"
                  jaloclass="com.local.core.jalo.MyCustomCronJob">
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="lastExportDate" type="java.util.Date">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

After created a new cronjob by extending AbstactJobPerformable and used a custom cronjob model.

```
public class MyCustomCronJob extends AbstractJobPerformable<MyCustomCronJobModel> {

   
    /**
     * @param cronJobModel
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public PerformResult perform(MyCustomCronJobModel cronJobModel) {

       // remaining logic
}
```

when I am trying to run a cronJob I am getting a class cast exception like we cannot cast CronJobModel to MyCustomCromJobModel

Error ::

```
Cannot cast 'de.hybris.platform.cronjob.model.CronJobModel' to 'com.local.core.jalo.MyCustomCronJobModel'
```

can someone please confirm if I am missing anything here and is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: It seem your MyCustomCronJobModel don't implement CronJobModel interface... Please add your MyCustomCronJobModel class

Comment: In first code snippet , I am already extending with CronJob.                        `itemtype code="MyCustomCronJob" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="CronJob"`

Comment: Can you tell us how did you create the `MyCustomCronJobModel` instance ? through impex ? (if yes, can you attach the file content?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating the wrong instance of the custom cron job.

Please use the below Impex to create a custom cron instance and execute it.

```
INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob   ;code[unique=true]  ;springId
                                ;myCustomJob    ;myCustomJob
                                
INSERT_UPDATE MyCustomCronJob   ;code[unique=true]  ;job(code); sessionLanguage(isocode); sessionCurrency(isocode)
;myCustomCronJob    ;myCustomJob    ; en ;EUR
```